# Removing unused nodes from JackRabbit versionStorage

Tags: jackrabbit

I have a scenario where a repository contains several version nodes that don't reference any `mix:versionable` nodes. This is because those versionable nodes have been removed from repository but not their corresponding versions.

This is causing that the JackRabbit Garbage collector cannot remove some files from datastore, because there are versions that still reference them, and consequently the disk space is not properly freed.

I tried to manually remove those versions with the following algorithm:

1. Obtain a version by its path, let's say: /jcr:system/jcr:versionStorage/40/05/a9/4005a9b2-51d1-4ed1-8c30-934409e05f86/1.14/jcr:frozenNode
2. Get the `jcr:frozenUuid` property from the obtained node
3. Get the node by identifier, using the frozenUuid from step 2
4. If no such node exists, remove the version

But in the last step I get the following exception:

```
javax.jcr.nodetype.ConstraintViolationException: Unable to perform operation. Node is protected.
```

So, my question is. How can I remove the version nodes that are unused?

I'm using jackrabbit-2.2.13.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I remove my versions...

```
String nodePath...
String versionName...
Session session...

VersionManager versionManager = session.getWorkspace().getVersionManager()
VersionHistory versionHistory = versionManager.getVersionHistory(nodePath);
versionHistory.removeVersion(versionName);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply TedTrippin. My original node does not exist anymore, it has been removed. So the line `versionManager.getVersionHistory(nodePath)` will throw an exception. My question is how to manipulate the versions, if you don't have the original node that generated the version in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you to traverse all the versions so that you can remove or restore.

```
        Node vs = session.getRootNode().getNode("jcr:system").getNode("jcr:versionStorage");
        Version v = traverseVersionStorage(vs, 0);

        private static Version traverseVersionStorage(Node n, int level)
                throws Exception {
            Version v = null;
            for (NodeIterator it = n.getNodes(); it.hasNext();) {
                Node n2 = it.nextNode();
                if (n2 instanceof Version && !n2.getName().startsWith("jcr:")) {
                    v = (Version) n2;
                    System.out.println("version " + n2.getName() + " of node "+ n2.getParent().getName() + ":");
                    Node n3 = n2.getNode("jcr:frozenNode");
                    VersionManager vman=session.getWorkspace().getVersionManager();
                        Node parent=n3.getParent();     
                        System.out.println(parent.getName());
                        vman.restore("/any/path/where/to/restore", v, true);
                        session.save();
                    }
                Version v2 = traverseVersionStorage(n2, level + 1);
                v = v == null ? v2 : v;
            }
            return v;
        }
```

below code is to traverse all versions of a node and remove by versionName

```
           VersionManager versionManager=jcrsession.getWorkspace().getVersionManager();
           VersionHistory vHistory=versionManager.getVersionHistory("/absolute/path/of/node/which/versions/to/be/removed");

                for (VersionIterator pt = vHistory.getAllVersions(); pt.hasNext();) 
                    {
                       Version p = pt.nextVersion();
                       if(p.getName()!="jcr:rootVersion")
                        {
                         vHistory.removeVersion(p.getName());
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Do you mean I should restore the version and then remove it? My question was no so much about traversing version nodes but how to remove them.

Comment: From this code you can find all versions of nodes, now you can either remove or restore according to requirement. Thanks.

Comment: My guess is that the line `vman.restore(...` will throw an exception, since in my scenario there is no current version of the node, because the node was deleted.

Comment: If a node is deleted and before deletion versioning of that node had been done. Then even after deletion versions are exist under jcr:system->jcr:versionStorage. So you can traverse from this code and remove it. Exception will be thrown in case of baseVersion restoration or removal. Thanks

Comment: I see. Could you add an example of removing the version after the restoration process? Another potential issue that I see, is that in your example, the restore will replace the current version with an older one, and will do the same in each loop iteration.

Comment: I had edited the answer, as you asked me to. Hope this will help in what you want.